# LLVM: Challenges in adding condition block at top of entry block

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

LLVM: Adding condition block at top of function(entry block) resulting in loosing optimizations like stack optimizations which are done at entry block

I'm tried to add condition block to all the APIs through compiler function pass.

Due to this, I'm observing stack optimization is getting missed as the initialization code moves out of entry block.

is there way to bring back  optimizations done by compiler on entry block on the new block? or can we combine entry and continue block someway??

Please share your thoughts on this?

**before adding condition block at top of the function**

```
**entry:**
  initialization call instructions
```

**After adding condition block at top of the function**

```
**entry**:
 %1 = call i32 @func1()
 %2 = icmp ne i32 %1, 0, !dbg
  br i1 %2, label %if.then.block, label continue

**continue:**
 ; initialization call instructions
ret void
**if.then.block**
   ; Insert instructions for the "if.then.block"
ret void
```

**Newly added:**
To be more specific, let's say we have a stack variable X of size 1000 bytes which is being set in 5 different places in the function.

**Before instrumenting** it stack size is always shown as addition of 1000

**After instrumentation**, stack size is getting added as 5 * 1000 which is 5000

I'm thinking this is happening because my function is losing some optimizations which is done at entry block whose contents are moved to new block due to my instrumentation.

Can some share pointers on how we can address this case?